# Inconsistent number of 'mines' added to my minesweeper game, I know what the bug is but am unable to fix

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set the mines number based on a global parameter, in this case its 4, however sometimes 3 are rendered and sometimes 4 are rendered,
my best guess is that the mines are being placed on top of each other since its supposed to be in random locations, tried fixing it but didn't work

The function:

```
function addBombs(board) {
    var coords = []
    for (var i = 0; i < gLevel.MINES; i++) {
        var randCol = getRandomIntInclusive(0, board.length - 1);
        var randRow = getRandomIntInclusive(0, board[0].length - 1);
        var cell = board[randRow][randCol]
        if(cell.isMine) continue;

        coords.push(cell)
        cell.isMine = true
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you should store the location of placed mines some where, so if the same location is generated again randomly you need to regenerate another location.

Comment: Because you're continuing when there actually IS a mine on the random cell you create

Comment: yeah but using break or return doesnt fix that either

Comment: kirnav would like an expample if you would be so kind

Comment: If the random selected cell isMine, generate another random cell until it is unique instead of continuing without creating the mine.

Comment: @AntiMAtter33 Of course, cause the same thing will happen with return or break :) Take a look at my answer

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer which came 15minutes after mine and was the exact same thing :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because when you detect that the random cell already has a mine in it, you are continuing the loop. The loop variable still gets incremented and your condition will not be met enough times to put a different mine somewhere else. You can instead do it like this:

```js
function addBombs(board) {
    var coords = []
    var i = 0;
    while (i < gLevel.MINES) {
        var randCol = getRandomIntInclusive(0, board.length - 1);
        var randRow = getRandomIntInclusive(0, board[0].length - 1);
        var cell = board[randRow][randCol]
        if(!cell.isMine) {
          coords.push(cell)
          cell.isMine = true
          i++;
        };
    }
}
```

This way if the cell already has a mine on it, your loop variable will not be incremented.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way, but ugliest too, to solve this is by decrementing your `i` variable.

```js
function addBombs(board) {
    var coords = []
    for (var i = 0; i < gLevel.MINES; i++) {
        var randCol = getRandomIntInclusive(0, board.length - 1);
        var randRow = getRandomIntInclusive(0, board[0].length - 1);
        var cell = board[randRow][randCol]
        if(cell.isMine) {
            i--;
            continue;
        }

        coords.push(cell)
        cell.isMine = true
    }

}
```

I recommend you to use a more elegant solution... try to change the `for loop` to a `while loop`.

```js
function addBombs(board) {
    var coords = []
    while(coords.length < gLevel.MINES){
        var randCol = getRandomIntInclusive(0, board.length - 1);
        var randRow = getRandomIntInclusive(0, board[0].length - 1);
        var cell = board[randRow][randCol];

        if(!cell.isMine) {
            coords.push(cell)
            cell.isMine = true
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the iteration still happens. i goes plus 1

```js
// Continue, means it will break the current iteration and go to the next
if(cell.isMine) continue;

//If you want the index to not advance, change to
if(cell.isMine){
  i--
  continue
}
```